# How to prove that a limit exists for $\lim_\limits{n\to \infty}\frac{n+2}{n} = 1$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

i know that if I want to prove that $\lim_\limits{n\to \infty}\frac{n+2}{n} = 1$, I have to use the Epsilon and Delta values, as following:
$$\left|\dfrac{n+2}{n}-1\right|<ε$$ 
$$\left|\dfrac{n+2-n}{n}\right|<ε$$
$$\left|\dfrac{2}{n}\right|<ε$$
$$\left|\dfrac{2}{ε}\right|<n$$

Then I assume that, $ = \left|\dfrac{2}{ε}\right|$, but I'm not sure how to proceed from here. Also the method in my lecture was a different to the one you see in mainly all explanations of limits. My professor used $$\frac{1}{n}≤\frac{1}{N_ε}≤\frac{1}{1/n}=ε$$ to explain the idea of limits, which has me insanely lost.

Comment: Please write down the definition of $\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n=L.$ See the diference with the $\epsilon-\delta$ case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$a_n = \dfrac{n+2}{n};$

$|a_n -1| =\dfrac{2}{n} .$

Let $\epsilon >0$ be given.

Choose  $M \ge 2/\epsilon$, $M $, real. positive.

There is a $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n_0 >  M.$
(Archimedes)

For $n\ge n_0 ;$

$|a_n-1| = 2/n \lt 2/n_0 \lt 2/M \le \epsilon, $

I.e. $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n =1$.

Comment: Why did you choose both $M$ and $n_0$?

Comment: Definition : For (any) epsilon >0 there is a n_0 such that for n>n_0 |a_n-L| < epsilon. Correct? This means limit a_n to L. Now how do we get the n_0 in your case. We take n_0 > 2/epsilon. The M is just an intermediate  step: We call 2/epsilon M, then n_0 is > M. Does this make sense?

Comment: I'm saying you don't need to have both $M$ and $n_0$

Comment: By Archimedes there is $n_0\in \Bbb N$ with $n_0>2/\varepsilon$. Including the $M$ is not wrong, just unnecessary.

Comment: Ok, do without M. So you have a n_0 gt 2/epsilon.

Answer (score 0):

You want: given any distance $\epsilon>0$, there is some $N_\epsilon$ (depending on $\epsilon$, hence the subscript) such that for all $n\geq N_\epsilon$, $\frac{n+2}{n}$ is within distance $\epsilon$ with the proposed limit $1$.

You've shown: $|\frac{n+2}{n}-1|=|\frac{2}{n}|=\frac{2}{n}$. And if $n\geq N_\epsilon$, then $\frac{2}{n}\leq\frac{2}{N_\epsilon}$. So to ensure $\frac{2}{n}<\epsilon$, it is enough to ensure $\frac{2}{N_\epsilon}<\epsilon$ which is equivalent to $N_\epsilon>\frac{2}{\epsilon}$. So, for example, pick $N_\epsilon=1+\lceil\frac{2}{\epsilon}\rceil$.

Comment: Sorry for the dumb comment, but wouldn't you have to find the value of $N_ε$ and then go on?

Comment: @SkiMask I did: $N_\epsilon=1+\lceil\frac{2}{\epsilon}\rceil$. Of course, any $N_\epsilon$ greater than $1+\lceil\frac{2}{\epsilon}\rceil$ also works.

Answer (score 0):

You will arrive at something like what your professor wrote to you after you have sufficient amount of experiences with the epsilon-analysis. For the current problem, just note that 
$$
|\frac{n+2}{n}-1| = \frac{2}{n}
$$
for all $n$; given any $\varepsilon > 0$, we have $2/n < \varepsilon$ if $n > 2/\varepsilon$. So taking $N := 1+ \lceil 2/\varepsilon \rceil$, i.e. $1$ plus the smallest integer $\geq 2/\varepsilon$, suffices.